# Do Django excecute scripts at server or in browser?

Tags: python, django

Hello :) My task is to write a web framework for a Python program with some massive calculations, which are desired to be executed at proper server and the result should be sent to the browser after it's calculated. My question is - is Django the right framework for that purpose? I tried to find out where Django executes scripts, but I haven't found any satisfying answer, so I hope that I would find one here.

Thank you for any attention.

Comment: The browser only executes JavaScript, generally. Django is written in Python - so it's definitely server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

django is a server side application